# JQuery Modal Dialog Form Submission

Tags: dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a JQuery Modal Form and when i add the submit event, it cannot display as dialog but rather than embedded into browser window. If I uncomment the click event below, it will embedded into browser window rather than show as dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        //$("#moveTicketBtn").click() {
        //  $("#moveUnknownTicket").submit();
        //};


        $("#moveUnknownTicketDialog").dialog(
        {
            title: "Move Unknown Ticket",
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true, 
            resizable: true, 
            stack: true, 
            width: 500, 
            height: 350 
        }); 




    });
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is like this? Please help. Thanks.

EDIT Question:

I have a form inside this dialog and upon submission(onsubmit, onblur) the javascript is not called. What is the reason?

Comment: I have a form inside this dialog and upon submission, the form event -> (onsubmit, onblur) does not called the javascript. What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$("#moveTicketBtn").click(function() {
  $("#moveUnknownTicket").submit();
});
```

you have to insert your function within the () of the click event.

more information here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: The .submit() method does not fire the onsubmit() event.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/uQCKJ/

As you can see the form is submitted, since the alert box is triggered

```
    $("#moveTicketBtn").click(function() {
    $("#moveUnknownTicket").submit();
});
```

I have put submit inside click function though works great.